# How to proxy websocket and http to different ports using nginx?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, websocket

I'am trying to achieve this:

1. serve static files (location /)
2. serve endpoints (location /app/ ) to server running on localhost:8080
3. proxy websocket (location /ws/ ) to server running on localhost:8081

I am not able to get all of these working at once. The issue is with websocket. I try to connect to it's port from react frontend.

```
const ws = new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:8081/ws/`);
```

I get:

```
[Error] WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8081/ws/' failed: Could not connect to the server.
```

nginx.conf:

```
Password:
user  www;
worker_processes 1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/example.error.log debug;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        #listen [::]:80 default_server;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

        root /www/pages;

        index index.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /app/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }

        location /ws/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

    }
}
```

I can only connect to websocket when I use root location (/):

```
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
```

How to get all 3 working?

Comment: Your error message says you are trying to connect to ws://localhost:8081/ws/, but in the NGINX-config your server is listening on port 80